# android:Asynchronous downloads list of images from ftp Servicer

Tags: android, asynchronous, ftp, download

I'm looking for a java library that works on the android that can Asynchronous download and display images  from an FTP server. Does anyone know of such a library. I've found lots of client apps, but no stand alone libraries.

Comment: Display Images likes Waterfall Stream in the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want FTPClient which is found in apache common net, you can download it from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi), it's a java standalone lib that works with android, [here is a simple tutorial](http://wiki-android.blogspot.com/2012/12/creating-android-ftp-client-ftp.html)

Comment: in fact,i already use commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar for that,the key point is i have no idea how to use Asynchronous downloads and imageCache between FTPServicer!

Comment: have a look here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ you may find what you need

Comment: Thanks for your help,pal!months ago i has read this page through Google,how stupid i am,i still was't find the key!could  you share some like FTP Demo closer!Thanks very much!

Comment: Does tihs helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605622/how-to-download-a-file-from-ftp-server-to-android-device