# How to download a file from FTP server to Android device?

Tags: android, ftp

I have a requirement *to download a image from FTP server to android device*. I tried with few samples by using **`ftp4j-1.7.2.jar`** library, but **failed to connect with FTP servers** & messed up.

Have anyone worked with FTP servers?

Please suggest to make connection & download file from Server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use library [commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)

Check below code to download file from FTP server:

```
private Boolean downloadAndSaveFile(String server, int portNumber,
    String user, String password, String filename, File localFile)
    throws IOException {
FTPClient ftp = null;

try {
    ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect(server, portNumber);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Connected. Reply: " + ftp.getReplyString());

    ftp.login(user, password);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Logged in");
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Downloading");
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                localFile));
        success = ftp.retrieveFile(filename, outputStream);
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }

    return success;
} finally {
    if (ftp != null) {
        ftp.logout();
        ftp.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I Installed FileZilla FTP server in my desktop. Its address is 127.0.0.1, Port is 14147. What I have to give for UserName, Password, fileName, localfile??

Comment: Use this link http://lifehacker.com/339887/build-a-home-ftp-server-with-filezilla to create a user with filezilla & to know that how to use it.    OR check this for same setups http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-setup-personal-ftp-server-using-filezilla-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: What is the Library you are using??? I am geting java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:471)